# Random "Compilation error: Error: 13 INTERNAL: exit status 1". No clue how to resolve or even what causes this error

Tags: compile, ide, analogwrite, digitalwrite, delay

I am a beginner with Arduino. I have a program that is intentionally simple.

The code refuses to compile, spitting out the error `Compilation error: Error: 13 INTERNAL: exit status 1`. I have gotten this type of error multiple times, and I have no idea what causes it, nor how to fix it.

My code is below, by the way.

```c++
void setup() {
  pinMode(9, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(10, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(11, OUTPUT);

  analogWrite(10, 10);
}

void loop() {
  digitalWrite(9, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(11, LOW);
  delay(250)
  digitalWrite(9, LOW);
  digitalWrite(11, HIGH); 
}
```

Comment: comment out all lines ... then uncomment one at a time ... compile each time

Comment: might it be your board config? ide does some annoying stuff sometimes regarding where it caches crud, making getting a truly clean install more annoying than it should be.

Comment: If you read all the error message you'll see it complaining about a missing semicolon...

Answer (score 4):

The problem with that error message is that you are only reading the very last line. That line says "Oops, it didn't compile". The *actual* error message occurs *before* that. You need to read the entire message to know what is going on.

With your code, for example, you get the following output:

```
blah.ino: In function 'void loop()':
blah.ino:13:3: error: expected ';' before 'digitalWrite'
   digitalWrite(9, LOW);
```

That is your *actual* error. It's telling you that there's a semi-colon missing before the `digitalWrite` on line 13.  There's nothing before the `digitalWrite` on line 13, but, if you look closely, you can see that line 12 has the semi-colon missing from the *end* of it.:

```cpp
  delay(250)    <---- missing ;
  digitalWrite(9, LOW);
```

Thus it proves that it is always important to both read and (if you don't understand it) post **the entire error message not just the last line.**

Comment: Thanks, that works.